# While loop instead of Union all in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got 2 database names db1name and db2name. I am writing the following query in SQL to get the table names. But I am doing `union all` to combine 2 database tables. In reality I have many databases, so can we create a while loop so that it takes all the database names in the while loop?

```
select * from
db1name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Union all
select * from
db2name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: If your database names aren't coming from user input, you can do this with dynamic sql.

Comment: Can you? Yes, of course. So where would you find all the database names that exist within a sql server instance? In the master database - sys.databases.

Comment: master databases

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if you need to do this, use dynamic SQL. As I don't know the version, I've used the older `FOR XML PATH` method, rather than `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
USE master;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF +
                         N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.[name]) + N'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
                  FROM sys.databases d
                  WHERE d.database_id > 4
                  ORDER BY d.database_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,13,N'') + N';';

PRINT @SQL; --YOur best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```